# Count how many fields a model has

Tags: django

I am wondering if there is a way to know how many fields a model contains.

Example:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    sub_title = models.TextField()
    summary = models.TextField()
```

I can count it but I would like to know if there is an in-built method that allows me to do so.

Ideally the quesry/code would be:

`Post.number_of_fieds`-->output--> `4`

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no builtin, you can obtain the fields with:

```
>>> len(Post._meta.fields)
5
```

We can define that on a `BaseModel` class and subclass this, to make such function available to all subclasses:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def number_of_fields(cls):
        return len(cls._meta.fields)

class Post(BaseModel):
    title = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    sub_title = models.TextField()
    summary = models.TextField()
```

The `.fields` return an `ImmutableList` of fields defined on that model. We can use `.get_fields()` to take into account the relations that are targetting that model as well.

Then we can query like:

```
>>> Post.number_of_fields()
5
```

Note however that this will return `5`, since the model has an (implicit) primary key here.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
>>> Post._meta.fields.__len__()
5
```